# Attach embedded object in Excel Sheet to Outlook Mail item

Tags: vba, outlook

Using VBA, I would like to attach an object (in my case PDF) embedded in an excel sheet to an Outlook mail item. Did some trial and error, SO and docset check. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add

If I am not mistaken, the Attachments.Add function seems to only take a file from disk... Is there any other solution?

Many thanks in advance!

Kai

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right avenue. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment. So, you can automate Excel and save the embedded file to the disk. Only then you will be able to attach your PDF file to a mail item in Outlook. See [Communicating with Other Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/communicating-with-other-applications) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. Not sure about your link though. Would have assumed to work with the OLEObject class to work with the embedded PDF:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oleobjects. What do you recommend? Thanks!